# Why can I not refine an object key in TS?

Tags: typescript

As the title says, I can't seem to refine the key on an object and am wondering what I'm doing wrong.

[typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20x%3A%20%7B%20key%3F%3A%20number%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Aif%20(typeof%20x.key%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(x.key)%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20y%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0A%0Aif%20(typeof%20y%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(y)%3B%0A%7D)

```js
const x: { key?: number } = {};

if (typeof x.key === 'number') {
    console.log(x.key); // typescript sees `x.key` as `number | undefined` still
}

let y: number | undefined;

if (typeof y === 'number') {
    console.log(y); // typescript sees `y` as `number`
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting the same result as you. Running with 3.3.1 locally I get 'undefined' for both x.key and y, unless I assign a value to the variable.

Comment: "typescript sees `x.key` as `number | undefined` still" --- are you sure? It totally is a `number` here (ts v3.3.3) and in playground it's `number` as well.

Comment: Enable all options in the TS playground and check http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20x%3A%20%7B%20key%3F%3A%20number%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Aif%20(typeof%20x.key%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(x.key.toFixed())%0A%7D%0A%0Ax.key.toFixed()%0A

Comment: The playground code is not complaining i.e. no warnings. What version of typescript are you running this in?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20x%3A%20%7B%20key%3F%3A%20number%2C%20key2%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20key2%3A%20undefined%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aif%20(typeof%20x.key%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x.key%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aif%20(typeof%20x.key2%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x.key2%3B%0A%7D -- better example.
 The playground isn't complaining, but when you mouseover `key` in the `if`, it shows the type as `?number`, while `key2` shows as just `number`

Comment: TS should be working properly here. To get some more clear insight into what TS sees you can try inferring the type of `x.key` by setting it to a new variable: `const z = x.key;` infers `const z: number`. This intermediate variable shouldn't be necessary in your final code.

Comment: See this example with `strictNullChecks` enabled to see TS working as expected and preventing misuse: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20x%3A%20%7B%20key%3F%3A%20number%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20a(myVal%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aa(x.key)%3B%0Aif%20(typeof%20x.key%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x.key%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a(x.key)%3B%0A%7D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expression x.key could have side effects so compiler can't guarantee type

```
class X {
  private firstTime = true; 
  get key(): number | undefined { 
    if (this.firstTime) { 
      this.firstTime = false;
      return 1;
    }
    return  undefined;
  }
}

const x: { key?: number } = new X();

console.log(typeof x.key); // number
console.log(typeof x.key); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly sure what you're trying to achieve here, but `typeof` plays three roles (thanks @MikeHill) in TypeScript;

1. The exact same function as in javascript, used at runtime to give a string representation of a variables instantiated type.
2. Used in type declarations to 'copy' a type from an instantiated variable.
3. As a [type guard](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html), at runtime TS can infer the variable type inside a block inside a conditional typeof expression. The purpose of which is so that the TS compiler knows the available methods etc and can produce errors where appropriate.

I think you're trying to use typeof to achieve an outcome that it can't satisfy. Your example code could use some work, it's pretty unclear the behaviour that you're after.

Comment: I believe the question was about types, not runtime values.

Comment: Well the runtime use of typeof is pretty misleading, using typeof in a type declaration is a different thing entirely. He's trying to refine by type at runtime by the looks of things.

Comment: `number` is a built-in JS type and the conditions are acceptable discriminators that will be interpreted both at compile-time by TS (as [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards)) and at runtime by JS. He is using `typeof` correctly but appears to be misunderstanding his tooling.

Comment: @MikeHill, you've got it right in your comment on the question. TypeScript is correctly refining the type inside those blocks `const blah = x.key` gives `number` as the inferred type, as dictated by the type guards. There's clearly an expectation of something more though from the question.